# Delaying a specificed kernel task

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I am trying to write a kernel module which will delay a certain kernel task by some n seconds if it meets a certain condition.

I have found which tasks meet my condition just fine, and have the pid of the said task stored in a variable. What I need is a method which takes a task pid and a time (presumably in jiffies) and reschedules the execution of the program for n seconds in the future.

I have looked in sched.c but to no avail. I know about the likes of `schedule_timout()`, however I don't want to timeout the current task. I am also aware of `resched_task` from sched.c, however it only takes a timeout value and I can't pass the task to reschedule.

Note that I don't want to edit any Linux system files here, just my kernel module.

Comment: You can probably use get_task_pid() to get the task_struct for that pid and then switch is state to TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE and start a timer. Once this timer expire, switch back the state to TASK_RUNNING and schedule that task.

Comment: Currently the scheduling sub-system within the Linux kernel is NOT designed to allow external kernel modules to "plug-in" into the scheduler. Either you will need to modify and re-compile the Linux kernel or make-do with ugly/cute hacks to access/modify the task structs from a module/app.

Comment: Can you update the question with details of *"certain kernel task"* and the *"certain conditions"*. There could be ways to configure the existing Linux kernel to do what you want.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni I assume I can use set_task_state() to do what you are suggesting, however does setting the state to TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE actually stop the process from hogging resources? What I am trying to do (@TheCodeArtist) is delay/hinder a process if we are doing another specific task on our systems, as this task makes typing on the terminal very sluggish. So it's more of a case of delaying it such that the resources are freed (or at least partially freed).

Comment: If the task is the current task, you will have to call schedule() to switch to another task. But can't you simply use the realtime priorities to ensure whatever task you want to have priority over the other ones?